# Memory overflow Issue with exportin DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, datatable, export

I am using this code below to Export DataTable to Csv file.

```
public static void DataTableToCsv(System.Data.DataTable dt, string csvFile)
{
 try
  {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => "\"" + column.ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
  sb.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", columnNames));

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Out of Memory Exception Here
    {
      var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
      sb.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
    }
  TextWriter sUrl = new StreamWriter(csvFile, true, Encoding.Unicode);
  sUrl.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
  sUrl.Close();
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  throw;
 }
}
```

Basically i combine several hundred of sheets in a folder  to a DataTable , these sheets have different and common columns etc . So the total number of rows become very huge ver 500k maybe 1 million .

Using the code above i get `Out Of Memory Exception` . Any suggestion how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write each CSV line out individually rather than combining them into a single giant StringBuilder buffer.  Every place where you do "sb.AppendLine()", do "sUrl.WriteLine()" instead.

E.g.:

```
    public static void DataTableToCsv(System.Data.DataTable dt, string csvFile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TextWriter sUrl = new StreamWriter(csvFile, true, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => "\"" + column.ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
                sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Out of Memory Exception Here
                {
                    var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
                    sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1048568 REACHED perfectly :) , i think it added more from code but when loading the sheet it fails after this point.